# attribute contains selector not working for dynamically added attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following piece of code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[href*='window']").on("mouseover", function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'green');
  });
  $("a:eq(2)").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", "#window_1");
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#1_window">link 1</a>
<a href="#1_window_1">link 2</a>
<a href="#">link 3 (click to add substring "window")</a>
```

Here I'm basically trying to apply some css to `a` tags having the substring *'window'* in their *'href'* attribute on *'mouseover'* event.

The code works fine for ones with predefined attribute (having the specified substring) but fails for dynamically added attributes.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: @j08691 I think this is not a duplicate, I'm referring to *dynamically added attribute, not element.*

Comment: Actually it is. The event delegation syntax is what you need to fix your problem.

Comment: but I've already used the *.on("mouseover",function(){})* technique.

Comment: `$(document).on("mouseover", "a[href*='window']", function () {/**/});`

Comment: The you're either not reading or not understanding jQuery's event delegation syntax. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/npyxwnk6/